# Xpath to get the value of an element with Selected property

Tags: xpath

For the following XMl file,

```
<select id="pet" title="Pet" class="x8" onchange="" name="pet">

  <option></option>
  <option selected="" value="abc">Dog</option>
  <option value="def">Cat</option>
  <option value="ghi">Rabbit</option>

</select>
```

What is the Xpath to be able to get the value of the option with "Selected" property? (I need to get "abc")

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to get `value` attribute of `option` element having `selected` attribute :

```
/select/option[@selected]/@value
```

Comment: I tried this but it cannot locate the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

That would take all options

```
/select/option
```

That would take 2-nd option and read value attribute from it.

```
/select/option[2]/@value
```

Comment: There will be instances that the other options (Cat and Rabbit) will be selected so giving the node location will only get the value in the specified node.